# Search and replace a string as shown below

Tags: c, string, replace, yacc, lex

I am reading a file say x.c and I have to find for the string "shared". Once the string like that has been found, the following has to be done.

Example:

```
shared(x,n)
```

Output has to be

```
*var = &x;
*var1 = &n;
```

Pointers can be of any name. Output has to be written to a different file. How to do this?

I'm developing a source to source compiler for concurrent platforms using lex and yacc. This can be a routine written in C or if u can using lex and yacc. Can anyone please help? 
Thanks.

Comment: To much work for lex/yacc. Check out [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) instead, or possibly [`awk`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I am developing a source to source translator for concurrent platforms where programs are translated into a high level meta language and then translated to any other concurrent pgm language. I am just wondering if the above can be done somehow in C program so that I can place it in user subroutine section?

Comment: You might want to look at [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) and [llvm](http://llvm.org/). It's a complete C and C++ compiler set, and can be used as libraries to parse C and C++ code and perform and then you can write any code transformations you like, and write out the modified file as a valid C or C++ file without worries.

Comment: By the way, the arguments to this `shared` function, can they be any type of valid C expressions?

Comment: Thanks Joachim. They can only be variables separated by commas. no expressions allowed. Do u know an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If, as you state, the arguments can only be variables and not any kind of other expressions, then there are a couple of simple solutions.

One is to use regular expressions, and do a simple search/replace on the whole file using a pretty simple regular expression.

Another is to simply load the entire source file into memory, search using `strstr` for `"shared("`, and use e.g. `strtok` to get the arguments. Copy everything else verbatim to the destination.

Comment: Using regular expressions, it's a bit too complicated. I tried doing it but I wont know the variables before hand. So there has to be a routine for this, isn't it? The second one seems like a good one but I haven't tried those anytime. Is it possible to provide me a function that does this please? Thank you.

Comment: Sir, If you copy everything else to verbatim to the destination how will a new pointer be pointing to the address of the variables copied?

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the C preprocessor.

Put this at the top of the file

```
#define shared(x,n) { *var = &(x); *var1 = &(n); }
```

and run in through `cpp`. This will include external resources also and replace all macros, but you can simply remove all `#something` lines from the code, convert using injected preprocessor rules and then re-add them.

By the way, why not a simple macro set in a header file for the developer to include?

A doubt: where do `var` and `var1` come from?

EDIT: corrected as shown by johnchen902

Comment: Thanks. We will not know the variables inside the parenthesis of shared. There may be "n" number of variables. For every such variable there has to be a pointer pointing to the address of that variable. Var and Var1 are two pointers that I have taken to show as an example. It can be anything. Thank you.

Comment: A very very simple answer would be: do it singularly on each variable. Do you know the "destination" variable name or is it generated?

Comment: input= shared(a,b,c, ... ,) output: *pointer=&a, *pointer1=&b and so on

Comment: I repeat, the `var`, `var1`... names are generated by your translator or are provided by the user somewhere? Also, what do you expect shared to return?

Comment: var, var1 and so on has to be generated by the translator. We just have shared(a,b,c,.....). We have to translate this *pointer=&a, *pointer1=&b and so on.

Comment: Ok, this is not possible whith the C pre processor. You might extract the params list, split arguments at commas and programmatically generate statements using a counter which increments. Do they need to be separate variables? Have you thought about an array?

Comment: Yes, they have to be separate variables. Can you give me a function that does that please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to preprocessor, I'll do this:

```
#define shared(x,n) (*var=&(x),*var1=&(n))
```

Why I think it's better than esseks's answer?
Suppose this situation:

```
if( someBool )
    shared(x,n);
else { /* something else */ }
```

In esseks's answer it will becomes to:

```
if( someBool )
    { *var = &x; *var1 = &n; }; // compile error
else { /* something else */ }
```

And in my answer it will becomes to:

```
if( someBool )
    (*var=&(x),*var1=&(n)); // good!
else { /* something else */ }
```